# caja is broken in Mate 21.10 after last update

Tags: mate, 21.10, caja

Kernel Linux 5.13.0-20-generic x86_64
MATE 1.26.0

My problem now is that caja is broken.  When invoked, it will spin forever in the home directory.  I can click off to another directory or drive on the left side and it works but it refuses to open my home directory or anything under it.  This is identical on 2 computers.

How to fix it?

Comment: That is why so many people wait a few months after the update to upgrade. Not trying to sound insensitive, but it you decided to download while the binaries were still hot off the press, then you signed up for it.

Comment: You can report a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/caja)

Comment: FYI, most users in this site are not associated with Canonical. I have edited to remove your rant.

Comment: What is the affected version of Caja? You can find it from `apt show caja`.

Comment: *rants in disguise* are off-topic on this user-support site.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask   (`caja` isn't Canonical supported anyway; it's a community supported application found on a community supported Ubuntu *flavor*).

Comment: works fine on my MATE instance upgraded from 21.04 same kernel version. What happens if you select `try ububntu` from a live USB or DVD